# Why does one stove top burner spark the other and vise versa?

Tags: stove

I have a two front stove top burners, burner A and burner B.

When I "ignite" A it will spark the spark plug for A & B.

When I "ignite" B it will also spark the spark plug for A & B.

its a stainless steal simple GE stove top and oven. Not sure what the model is.

Comment: Has it always done this?  Or is this something new?

Comment: seems to be something new, I've never noticed it before.

Comment: You should use edit to add that fact to your question.  Edit will get you renewed attention, and that is an important fact.

Answer (score 3):

There is a single spark igniter with two ignition gaps.

You have a single igniter that when triggered sparks every burner.

It ensures that if you left on the gas on the other burner, it would light and you would turn it off. Either that or the manufacturer did this to save on parts.

Comment: This is common practice among even high end ranges. I believe part of the logic is, you would not want to accidentally mis-wire the igniters so that if igniter attached to the valve for burner B was only igniting at Burner A or visa versa. That could cause serious issues (i.e. flameout/explosion)

Comment: I think you are right @Dan D. I tried it with the other burners and it seems to be behaving as you described.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply that there's only one spark generating circuit with several switches (and several spark gaps). Making separate circuits would add to the cost for no benefit, and switching the high voltage side isn't easy (you'd get  sparks inside the switches). So this is the simplest way.

Spark ignition that doesn't use mains electricity or batteries (i.e. piezoelectric ignition) similarly uses one spark generator with multiple outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are saying this is a problem. I just had the same issue with my Bosch stovetop when I had two burners going and a third burner, all in the back row, started sparking on its own. I had to allow the third one to ignite just to stop the sparking. When I finished cooking, turning off all the burners also stopped the third from sparking.

I called service and they told me this was a safety issue and they would send someone out to service it at their expense even though the unit is almost five years old. Of course, it took two weeks and the problem has never surfaced since that one time, and the service guy could find nothing wrong with the unit.

So it might be worth a call to customer service for your unit and see what they have to say.