# Should my stove's spark plugs all fire at once?

Tags: gas, stove, natural-gas, stove-top

I bought a second hand Bosch gas cooktop/stove and when I test its igniter - **without having connected it to a gas supply**, it only seem to spark for a single burner. If I move its igniter module wires around I can confirm that they all can spark. So I presumed this was an igniter module issue and replaced it with a brand new one, but it still does the same thing.

What do you think is the problem? Is it possible that this cooktop does this by default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does one stove top burner spark the other and vise versa?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/107887/why-does-one-stove-top-burner-spark-the-other-and-vise-versa)

Comment: How did you test the igniter? Does whichever burner that you turn on spark, and the others don't? Or is that there's only one burner that ever sparks, and the others don't, no matter which one you turn on?

Comment: This is common practice among even high end ranges. I believe part of the logic is, you would not want to accidentally mis-wire the igniters so that if igniter attached to the valve for burner B was only igniting at Burner A or visa versa. That could cause serious issues (i.e. flameout/explosion)

Answer (score 2):

They all spark at once since there is only one spark module.

Comment: The question is unclear. We don't know which burner sparks, nor what the OP's expectation is.

Comment: We have a newer gas range with 5 burners. When you try to light any burner, they all spark at the same time